# xlsxwriter refer to sheets inside worksheet.write_formula()

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to find a solution how to substitute the following:

```
worksheet = writer.sheets['Overview']
worksheet.write_formula('C4', '=MIN('Sheet_147_mB'!C2:C325)')
```

with something like:

```
for s in sheet_names:
    worksheet.write_formula(row, col, '=MIN(s +'!C2:C325')')
    row+=1
```

to iterate through all the existing sheets in the current xlsx book and write the function to the current sheet having an overview.

After spending some hours I was not able to find any solution therefore it would be hihgly appriciated if someone could point me to any direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't give the error message, but it looks like the problem is with your quoting - you can't nest single quotes like this: `'=MIN(s +'!C2:C325')')`, and your quotes aren't in the right places. After fixing those problems, your code looks like this:

```
for s in sheet_names:
    worksheet.write_formula(row, col, "=MIN('" + s +"'!C2:C325)")
    row+=1
```

The single quotes are now nested in double quotes (they could also have been escaped, but that's ugly), and the sheet name is enclosed in single quotes, which protects special characters (e.g. spaces).